# Uploading the NextJs app and building it produces strange issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am building a nextjs web and this is my first time building in NextJs. The web is working fine on the localhost but it doesn't work when I run the `npm run build` command or if I try to upload to some hosting service like Vercel or Firebase hosting.
It gives me strange errors. I am posting some error description below.

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'rL' before initialization
    at 52209 (/Users/salmanmajid/Desktop/React/NewPromptSavvy/promptsavvy/.next/server/app/dashboard/page.js:504:18)
    at t (/Users/salmanmajid/Desktop/React/NewPromptSavvy/promptsavvy/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at F (/Users/salmanmajid/Desktop/React/NewPromptSavvy/promptsavvy/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:91937)
    at /Users/salmanmajid/Desktop/React/NewPromptSavvy/promptsavvy/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94352
    at W._fromJSON (/Users/salmanmajid/Desktop/React/NewPromptSavvy/promptsavvy/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94790)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at N (/Users/salmanmajid/Desktop/React/NewPromptSavvy/promptsavvy/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:91658)
    at t (/Users/salmanmajid/Desktop/React/NewPromptSavvy/promptsavvy/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:98043)

Error occurred prerendering page "/dashboard". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'rL' before initialization
    at 52209 (/Users/salmanmajid/Desktop/React/NewPromptSavvy/promptsavvy/.next/server/app/dashboard/page.js:504:18)
    at t (/Users/salmanmajid/Desktop/React/NewPromptSavvy/promptsavvy/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at F (/Users/salmanmajid/Desktop/React/NewPromptSavvy/promptsavvy/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:91937)
    at /Users/salmanmajid/Desktop/React/NewPromptSavvy/promptsavvy/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94352
    at W._fromJSON (/Users/salmanmajid/Desktop/React/NewPromptSavvy/promptsavvy/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94790)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at N (/Users/salmanmajid/Desktop/React/NewPromptSavvy/promptsavvy/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:91658)
    at t (/Users/salmanmajid/Desktop/React/NewPromptSavvy/promptsavvy/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:98043)
```

I am attaching the whole [source code](https://github.com/E8-Labs/PromptAIWeb-Salman-Next.git).
I am not sure where I can resolve this issue. It is something that next is adding after I run the `npm run build` command

Trying to upload the project to vercel. Before I do that, I run the `npm run build` command and I get the error described in the question.